# Linux Mint Mate 16 cannot automatically connect to home Wi-fi

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, linux-mint

I have Linux Mint 16 32-bit installed with Mate desktop environment on LG-R590 notebook. The problem is although a lot of SSIDs are displayed when the network icon on the bottom right is clicked, the network I intent to connect(home Wi-fi) to is not displayed. I have to connect to the network as if it were a secret network, and the connection work seamlessly in this manner but I would like to automatize the process since my mother will also be using the PC regularly. The modem is Airties 5343 and uses WPA2 encryption with a password of 10 characters of length. How can I have the computer recognize and connect to this network without user interference? Any contribution and suggestion is welcome please do not hesitate to post.

Thanks

Comment: Other Wi-Fi devices can see that network?

Comment: @Cornelius Yeah and they connect seamlessly I have another dual-boot laptop with Win 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 and it connects without a problem, also my tablet (Android-Samsung Galaxy) can connect to this network. At the moment I am writing from the problematic computer but I have to connect manually as if it were a secret network(SSID hidden) which is not the case as I checked from the router settings.